# UILocalNotification always shows up as soon as I load my app regardless of the fire date

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsusernotificationcenter

Hello I am new to swift and IOS programming. I have set up 6 notifications that are supposed to alert the user 6 times a day depending on the time of day. The alerts are working but for some reason when the app first launches all 6 alerts show up in the notification center at the same time. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

this is the code in the AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.



        let notificationTypes : UIUserNotificationType = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge
        let notificationSetting : UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSetting)

        return true
    }
```

this is my function for the six different notifications

```
func prayerAlert (prayerName : String, prayHour : Int, prayMinute : Int) {


        dateComp.year = Int(currentDate.year)
        dateComp.month = Int(currentDate.month)
        dateComp.day = Int(currentDate.day)
        dateComp.hour = prayHour
        dateComp.minute = prayMinute
        dateComp.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone()

        var calender : NSCalendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSGregorianCalendar)!
        var date : NSDate = calender.dateFromComponents(dateComp)!

        var notification : UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = prayerName
        notification.fireDate = date



        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }
```

and this is where I'm calling the function in the ViewDidLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        pray.setTimeFormat(0)


        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()


        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            self.locationManager.delegate = self
            self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        }



        var timesArray = pray.getDatePrayerTimes(currentDate.year, andMonth: currentDate.month, andDay: currentDate.day, andLatitude: locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, andLongitude: locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude, andtimeZone: pray.timeZone)


            var convertedTime = convertPrayArray(timesArray as NSMutableArray)

            prayerAlert("Time for Fajr", prayHour: convertedTime.hourArray[0], prayMinute: convertedTime.minuteArray[0])
            prayerAlert("Time for SunRise", prayHour: convertedTime.hourArray[1], prayMinute: convertedTime.minuteArray[1])
            prayerAlert("Time for Dhuhr", prayHour: convertedTime.hourArray[2], prayMinute: convertedTime.minuteArray[2])
            prayerAlert("Time for Asr", prayHour: convertedTime.hourArray[3], prayMinute: convertedTime.minuteArray[3])
            prayerAlert("Time for Maghrib", prayHour: convertedTime.hourArray[5], prayMinute: convertedTime.minuteArray[5])
            prayerAlert("Time for Isha", prayHour: convertedTime.hourArray[6], prayMinute: convertedTime.minuteArray[6])


    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update: **Xcode 7.1 • Swift 2.1**

The problem is that you are setting the date components to localTime zone instead of the notification.

add this extension NSDate to return the desired components from NSDate()

```
extension NSDate {
    var minute: Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Minute, fromDate: self)}
    var hour:   Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Hour,   fromDate: self)}
    var day:    Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Day,    fromDate: self)}
    var month:  Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Month,  fromDate: self)}
    var year:   Int { return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.Year,   fromDate: self)}
    func fireDateAt(hr: Int, min: Int) -> NSDate {
        let date = NSDate()
        return NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateWithEra(1,
            year: year,
            month: month,
            day: { hr > date.hour || (hr == date.hour && min > date.minute) ? day : day + 1 }(),
            hour: hr,
            minute: min,
            second: 0,
            nanosecond: 0
        )!
    }
}
```

> timeZone Property
>
> The time zone of the notification’s fire date.
>
> The date specified in fireDate is interpreted according to the value
>   of this property. If you specify nil (the default), the fire date is
>   interpreted as an absolute GMT time, which is suitable for cases such
>   as countdown timers. If you assign a valid NSTimeZone object to this
>   property, the fire date is interpreted as a wall-clock time that is
>   automatically adjusted when there are changes in time zones; an
>   example suitable for this case is an an alarm clock.

```
func prayerAlert (prayerName : String, prayHour : Int, prayMinute : Int) {
    var notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.timeZone  = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    notification.alertBody = prayerName
    notification.fireDate  = NSDate().fireDateAt(prayHour, min: prayMinute)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

Comment: I just tried that and its still the same behavior. Nothing changed

Comment: still the same exact behavior

Comment: No it is not the same behavior. that's what you think.

Comment: If you show how you declare your dateComp and currentDate would be easier to help you.

Comment: I have it declared under the ViewController class

Comment: Just add a new file to your project (Swift source file) and name it Main.swift. Put this extensions there. And change your code to the updated answer.

Comment: I did it exactly as you said and its still the same thing.

Comment: you need to set your fire date for tomorrow depending of the time of that's it is being set. you can solve it adding one day to your fire date

Comment: so if for example the user downloads my app in the morning he wont be able to get notifications until the next day? maybe I'm wrong can you please explain remember I'm still new at this.

Comment: You just have to compare the time of the notification against the local time and if already happened that day add 1 day otherwise don't.

Comment: ok so I just tried to manually fire the notification by manually entering the hour and minute and I didn't get any notifications even tho I set it a couple of minutes in the future

Comment: I have update the answer. I am sure it will behave as expected.

Comment: Perfect now it works!!!! I really appreciate your patience with me even tho I still need to understand exactly what you did and why it has to be this hard. Again thank you for putting up with me

Comment: I will definitely do that